# #1064 error with INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I have a PHP script produced by using Export in phpMyAdmin. When trying to Import elsewhere from that script I got all sort of errors. Thanks to this site I managed to modify it to this one and get further before an error crops up but I can't find help for this one.

**Original export**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Feb 23, 2015 at 05:23 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.95-log
-- PHP Version: 5.5.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `graveyard`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `adminId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `admin`
--

INSERT INTO `admin` (`adminId`, `userName`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');
```

**After looking at various questions I modified it to**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `terrier`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `terrier`.`admin` (
  `adminId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`adminId`))

--
-- Dumping data for table admin
--

INSERT INTO admin (`adminId`, `userName`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');
```

This gets as far as the INSERT INTO command but throws up error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`adminId`))


--
-- Dumping data for table admin
--

INSERT INTO admin (' at line 15
```

I suspect this is a problem due to different MySQL versions - or more likely my newby status.

Comment: adminId coloumn is an auto_increment so you dont have to give a value for it
`adminId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,

Comment: There are numerous problems with your revised version: including a missing comma between the definition of the `password` column and the declaration of the `PRIMARY KEY`; and no terminating `;` at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  Go back to the original version and let us know what errors you were experiencing with that.

Comment: Change `(1, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');` to `('', 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');` - Auto_increment does not let you enter a value; it just defeats the purpose. So, either you do that, or remove the AI from the column if you're going to use your own numbering system.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
The reason the OP is getting a syntax error is because a comma was left out following the declaration of the password column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `terrier`.`admin` (
  `adminId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL <-- should be a comma here
  PRIMARY KEY (`adminId`))
```

**NOTES ON INSERTING INTO AUTO-INCREMENT FIELDS**

You're trying to insert into an auto-incrementing field `adminId`. Don't specify a value for that, MySQL automatically takes care of it.

```
INSERT INTO admin (`userName`, `password`) VALUES ('wardens', 'Bega&1120');
```

If you want to explicitly place a value in your `INSERT` queries for the auto-increment field you have three choices based on specifying the field to be `NOT NULL`- `''`, `0`, or `NULL`. [Here is the reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

```
INSERT INTO admin (`adminId`, `userName`, `password`) VALUES ('', 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');
INSERT INTO admin (`adminId`, `userName`, `password`) VALUES (0, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');
INSERT INTO admin (`adminId`, `userName`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');
```

**UPDATE** Further testing (as suggested by @eggyal) reveals that *any* value can be inserted into auto-increment fields regardless of the database engine specified.

Comment: OP could also do `('', 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');` as outlined in the other answer in comments *Sam* ;-)

Comment: True *Ralph* but it is one of those things that gives me the willies ;-) I'm not even a fan of passing a 0 or NULL as the link I provided suggests I can. I'll modify the answer though.

Comment: As in a *Wee Willy Wonka* type of Willies *Sam*? [I also posted a comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899541/1064-error-with-insert-into#comment46060122_28899541) under OP's question.

Comment: Sorta' *Ralph* ;-) I saw your comment and I have tested all three of the examples I placed in the answer and they all work. What gives me the willies is that looking at the query seems a bit misleading, especially for newbies to databases. They may think they're actually placing one of those values into the column. Of course they'll learn *really* quickly that this is not the case @Fred-ii-

Comment: I'm thinking the same also. *However*, the error they've posted doesn't seem to support that of the query *Sam*.

Comment: I am a little surprised that everything but the table name ``admin`` is back ticked *Ralph*. Look at how the database is specified `terrier.admin` but the query just says `admin`.

Comment: That `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS terrier` (I removed the ticks around "terrier", you know how Stack hates ticks in highlights), with the admin after "terrier" is questionable. Who knows.

Comment: Looks like we learned something new @Fred-ii- *Mornin' Ralph*

Comment: That we did Jay; even us old dogs learn new tricks – *Mornin' Sam!* – I just can't rollover anymore, nor will I beg. But I will give a helping paw.

Comment: FWIW, the insertion of explicit values into `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns is *not* engine dependent.  The updated documentation clarifies this.

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Feb 23, 2015 at 05:23 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.95-log
-- PHP Version: 5.5.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `graveyard`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  adminId int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  userName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  primary key (adminId)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `admin`
--

INSERT INTO `admin` (`adminId`, `userName`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120')
```

Comment: Could you explain why you say it will work? Just so future visitors will know what the problem was.

Comment: How could that possibly work? You're trying to insert something into a field that auto-increments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- At his original export he didn't have a primary key.. Jay, My bad missed that part will edit that with yours if you're okay with that.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: It's perfectly legal to give an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column an explicit value if one so desires—all that `AUTO_INCREMENT` does is provide a value if none is given.

Comment: That has never been the case in my experience @eggyal. I am looking for references to what you're saying though. Here is what I've found ["You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers. If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: In order for this to work, `(1, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');` would need to be `('', 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');` - Upon testing, also received a syntax error.

Comment: @eggyal Your second link is broken. In any case both reference [InnoDB tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-traditional.html), not MyISAM as the OP is using.

Comment: FWIW, I have filed a [documentation bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76206).

Comment: @eggyal I am not *insisting* anything and I am sorry that I have touched a nerve. I went through a series of tests on MyISAM and InnoDB tables after  your posts and I found that you could enter certain values in auto-incrementing fields using `INSERT` and changed my answer accordingly. Perhaps there is something wrong with the way I've been configuring tables or the way my system is configured. BTW, I have no idea of what your years of experience are so there'd be no way I could disagree with that. ;-)

Comment: No worries @eggyal! I learned something new and in the process found the OP's real error. Thank you!

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Following my bug report, the MySQL documentation has now been updated.  [Numeric Type Attributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) and [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) both now explicity state "*When you insert any other value into a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the inserted value.*"

Comment: Awesome @eggyal! One less bit of confusion.