# I'm Trying to insert some Data into MySqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I'm facing a problem in inserting some data into mysqli 
i tried everything same problem i don't know what's wrong 
here is the code

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "root");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}   
function data($url, $items){
    $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    switch($domain){
        case 'test':
        foreach($items as $item){
            $tmp = explode("/", $item['link']);
            $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
            $author =  ucwords(str_replace($arr, '', str_replace('-', ' ', $tmp[4])));
            $description = strip_tags($item['description']);
            $source = "Quoteee";
            $img = "";
            $date = date();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (id, quote, author, source, img, date, activated) VALUES
                    (NULL, '".$quote."', '".$author."', '".$source."', '".$img."', '".$date."', 1)";
            $insert_row = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if($insert_row){
                print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
            }else{
                die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But What is the problem

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you checked the error log?

Comment: if your database table's id field is set to an integer type and NOT NULL, then you have to take out the 'NULL' from your query and replace with an integer type. Better still, if the id field is an auto-increment field, then you don't need to pass include the id in your query, it will be auto-handled.

Comment: How is the `id` field defined in your table?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (quote, author, source, img, date, activated) VALUES
      ('".$quote."', '".$author."', '".$source."', '".$img."', '".$date."', 1)";
Something like this?

Comment: No, from the `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Comment: @mikeO. see the comments below paddfields answer. `NULL` is allowed here.

Comment: The problem is that you never call the `data` function. When you do you will also have to pass in the connection information or the queries will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reread all your code and figured out that you initialized your mysql connection outside your function. To fix the problem you should move initialization into your function:

```
function data($url, $items){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "root");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    } else {   

      $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
      switch($domain){
  ...
```

or you can try call global var like:

```
function data($url, $items){
  global $mysqli;
  ...
```

But I would prefer 1st variant.

And the part I started from will help you to avoid sql injection and makes code more clear and easy to read and understand:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO quote (quote, author, source, img, date, activated) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1)");

$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $quote, $author, $source, $img, date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date));
$stmt->execute();

$insert_row = $stmt->affected_rows;
if($insert_row){
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. This will fail because you're not binding the correct number of variables for the insert statement.

Comment: @NiNjA_HacKeR did you see any before? show that error to everybody then? :-) it would help a lot!

Comment: @NiNjA_HacKeR try my updated query, I've removed `id`  from there, I guess you have that as auto_increament field?

Comment: See my latest comment on your oriaginal post @NiNjA_HacKeR - you never call the `data()` function and you're not passing in the database connection.

Comment: @Alex you still have a column count bind mismatch.

Comment: @JayBlanchard which one?

Comment: @JayBlanchard activated value is set as constant **1** in query, there is no bind for that field. isn't it?

Comment: your query is OK now @Alex, I had missed that column in your insert. The query is not the problem in this case. The OP never calls the function containing the database and doesn't pass the database connection into the function. No errors will be generated until he actually calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting a NULL id each time, which I suspect is the problem.

If the id is auto incremented then simply leave it out of the insert query.

The query may be failing because the field is set to NOT NULL in the database

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (quote, author, source, img, date, activated) VALUES ('".$quote."', '".$author."', '".$source."', '".$img."', '".$date."', 1)";
```

Comment: [NULL is allowed.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899541/1064-error-with-insert-into) From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) - *"**If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column** to generate sequence numbers. When you insert any other value into a AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the inserted value. "*

Comment: But it may be set to NOT NULL - the OP hasn't specified

Answer (score 0):

The mysql database object should be within the scope of the function data.

use the variable as global or place it inside the function